# Pivot Table interfering with find in column

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table

I am trying to find a specific value in a column, however there is a pivot table (occasionally) part way down the page that sometimes extends through this column. 
If the pivot table has extended through the column, my program crashes. If it doesn't, then the code runs fine.
"MonthlyStartDate is a string "August 2013".

```
LastRowMonthly = DataPage.Range["AT:AT"].Find(MonthlyStartDate, Type.Missing, XlFindLookIn.xlValues, XlLookAt.xlWhole, XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, XlSearchDirection.xlNext, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing).Row;
```

I have tried limiting the search to only the rows the date could appear in, 
`Range["AT7:AT48"]` 
This makes no difference though. If the pivot table runs into the column it crashes, if it doesn't then it runs fine.

The pivot table starts on line 52 in a different column and cannot be moved.
I also tried researching how to collapse the date column field on the pivot table, which is the field that causes the table to run into column AT. This has bore no fruit though. If anyone knows how this is done that would certainly solve my issue.

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so i figured out how to do it.

```
DataPage.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Years").ShowDetail = false;
DataPage.Range["AT:AT"].Columns.AutoFit();
```

Adding this in before the Find will collapse the "Years" column, preventing the dates from overlapping into the path of my Find.

After finding this though, i realised it still wasn't working, but thankfully realised why before i wrote off my findings as rubbish.
In my Find, i am looking at the values in the column. When the pivot table extends over the column, it resizes the column to fit the pivot data, which makes the column too small to show the full date leaving only "##" showing.
by setting the "AutoFit" on the column after minimising the pivot table, it shows the full date value again, and enabling my Find to produce an answer.

hopefully this will help someone in the future. (If they can make sense of my ramblings.)